# How to reload child component when the state of parent class changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in Parent class, I pass the item to child component.

```
<InfoWidget bar={this.state.bar}> 
</InfoWidget>
```

then,receive data and use `prop.bar` here

```
const InfoWidget = (props) =>{
  const [length, setLength] = useState([]);
  const classes = useStyles();
  useEffect(() => {
 
    setLength( props.bar * 10);
  }, []);
  return(
    <Paper> 
     {length}
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

First load it works well, but when the state.bar of parent class changed, child component is not reloaded.

I want to reload the child component ,every time the value of parent class changed.

Where should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLength(props.bar * 10);
}, [props.bar]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add key to parent, when the `key` changes it will rerender the component

```
<InfoWidget key={this.state.bar} bar={this.state.bar}> 
</InfoWidget>
```